# cho-han bakuchi em C basico

Tags: c, números-aleatórios

Estou tendo uma dúvida no programa que fiz para representar o jogo cho-han bakuchi, esse jogo tem como regra rolar dois dados de 6 lados em um copo antes de mostrar os dados se faz a aposta na qual o jogador fala cho(pares) ou han(ímpar) e depois os dados são mostrados e somado os seus valores.

no meu programa o jogo funciona exceto pelo rolamento de dado, estou usando a função time e srand dessa forma:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

O problema é que depois que o programa e compilado e executado o time(tempo do relógio no meu pc) é salvo então sempre que os dados rolarem eles vão rolar o mesmo numero pois o *srand* está salvo no horario X por exemplo *14:32:43* digamos que os dados rolem 4 e 4 sempre gostaria de saber como que eu faço para mudar isso pois não importa quantas vezes eles rolem sempre vai ser 4 e 4 gostaria que sempre cada dado foce aleatório o que eu faço?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int die1;
int die2;
int sum;

int main()
{
    int x, cred=100, y, apost;

    srand(time(NULL));

    die1=1+(rand()%6);
    die2=1+(rand()%6);
    sum=die1+die2;

    while(cred!=0)
    {

        printf("faça a aposta:(digite -1 para sair)\n");
        scanf("%d", &apost);

        cred=cred-apost;

        printf("\nescolha 1-cho(par) 2-han(impar):\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);

         printf("\njogador rolou %d+%d=%d\n", die1,die2,sum);

        switch(x)
        {
            case 1:
                if(sum%2==0)
                {
                    printf("ganhou!\n");
                    cred=cred+(apost*2);
                    printf("seus creditos sao:%d\n",cred);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("perdeu!");
                    printf("seus creditos sao:%d\n",cred);
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                if(sum%2!=0)
                {
                    printf("ganhou!\n");
                    cred=cred+(apost*2);
                    printf("seus creditos sao:%d\n",cred);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("perdeu!");
                    printf("seus creditos sao:%d\n",cred);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

O problema aqui é que o valor de [`time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) é o mesmo todo o segundo. Então se você abrir o programa duas vezes no mesmo segundo vai ter exatamente a mesma saída. Uma alternativa simples é usar a função do Windows [`GetTickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx), que avança em milissegundos:

```
#include <windows.h>
srand(GetTickCount());
```

Mas talvez milissegundos ainda seja lento de mais (se você executar o programa em um loop por exemplo). Uma alternativa é a [`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397(v=vs.85).aspx) que avança em 0.1 microsegundos. Isso deve ser rápido o suficiente para qualquer propósito prático.

```
#include <windows.h>
FILETIME ft;
GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);
srand(ft.dwLowDateTime);
```

No Linux pode fazer usando a [`gettimeofday`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday), assim:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
struct timeval time; 
gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
srand((time.tv_sec * 1000) + (time.tv_usec / 1000));
```

Comment: ^^ obrigado vou dar uma olhada =)) e era bem isso que eu queria saber, agora se eu precisar colocar um numero de jogadores aleatorios de 1 a 5 jogadores?

Answer (score 2):

Seu código está quase correto, apenas deve colocar esta parte dentro do while:

```
 srand(time(NULL));
 while(cred!=0)
    {
    die1=1+(rand()%6);
    die2=1+(rand()%6);
    sum=die1+die2;
 //...
```

Porque você definiu os números aleatórios antes do loop e não os alterou novamente.

E note que o `srand(time(NULL)` deve ficar fora do loop para garantir que os números serão aleatórios.

Comment: eita hahahaha verdade como nao flagei isso o obrigado, de qualquer forma eu iria ter notado